# What affects resistances?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Diablo 3, I haven't found any items with an "increase x resistance" attribute yet my character currently has +10 resistance across every element. How is that possible? What is affecting my resistance values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intelligence grants you resistance values.

Additionally, once you reach Nightmare (give or take), you'll start seeing equipment with bonuses to specific resistances.

Answer (score 2):

Intelligence adds 0.1 resist all per point, you may just have 100 INT on the character.

Comment: Is there any cap on resistences?

Comment: [Good question...](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67306/is-there-a-cap-on-resistances)